# how to ignore spaces when retrieving data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working in PHP with PDO. The problem I am having is:
   I have a table called products. It has a column named `product_name`. Here are some examples of the name of products

```
product_name
----------
Bfilet de bœuf entier                    
Bar de ligne                             
Saumon entier
Beurre
```

So when I execute the query

```
select * from products where product_name='beurre'
```

It works fine. It returns the corresponding line.

But if I do:

```
select _ from products where product_name='Saumon entier'"
```

It does not return any result. There seems to be a problem when there are spaces involved!

And another unusual thing is that I don't seem to be having this problem on the SQL Command line, only when I use PHP to retrieve the data.

Could someone explain to me why and offer a solution?

Comment: Is "select _ from" a typo?

Comment: This is just your speculation on the spaces role. You have to verify it before asking a question

Comment: As you suspect, you probably have a space after 'entier'. Cleanse your data before submitting to your database.

Comment: @brian demilia  yes that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Pattern matching

Lookup [MySQL pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html). Code would be something like:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute(['Saumon entier%']);

var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

After your edit, it appears you don't want `LIKE`, but you actually have a space at the end of the string. Quick fix would be:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE TRIM(product_name) = 'Saumon entier'
```

But really you should trim spaces on input.

#### Answer to question in comments

> if i have a french product name such as 'Côte de bœuf', Is there a way i can replace the accents?

In most cases, yes. If your database is `utf8` with e.g. `utf8_unicode_ci`, while `ci` meaning case-insensitive this would match:

```
SELECT 'Côte de boeuf' = 'cote de boeuf';

'Côte de boeuf' = 'cote de boeuf'
----------------------------------
                                 1
```

Note that I removed `œ` because that won't match, I am not sure to which character it translates.
Other option would be to store "non accented" product name in different column and match against those. Lookup `iconv` in PHP manual.

Comment: It may cure only symptom, but not dicease.

Comment: @YourCommonSense This answer is now wrong since the OP edited the question and it received other connotation :)

Comment: @TooTSKI Perfect! that worked, thanks alot. Ok but now i have another question, 
   For example, if i have a french product name such as 'Côte de bœuf', Is there a way i can replace the accents? So that to be looking for 'cote de boeuf'?

Comment: @Arj added to answer, depends on your case, but should be truthy.